# How to parallelize a node graph of tasks with dependencies

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of tasks, where directed edges represent dependencies. In order to parallelize the execution of tasks, I have experimented with a few techniques but I would like advice on the best way to approach this.

Here's an example graph with tasks `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. There is always 1 terminal node. In practical application, graphs may have thousands of nodes.

```
         C ---.
               \
A ----------------> D
   \           /
    `--> B ---`
```

- `A` has no dependencies; it can run immediately
- `B` depends on A being complete first. So if it runs on the same thread as `A`, no wait required. If it's on a different thread than `A`, it would require synchronization.
- `C` has no dependencies so it can run immediately
- `D` depends on `A`, `B`, and `C`, and its completion signals the completion for the whole graph

I've tried a couple improvised techniques, which work OK but **I feel like this is a problem there exists an optimal solution for already**.

Specifically this is a C++ audio application on Windows, and the node graph represents a DSP circuit which will run continuously over a buffer. So for example the best technique I've found so far generates an execution plan for N threads based on the timing of the nodes in the graph. The plan can be generated once, and then executed in a loop.

---

*edit*

So far the best technique I have tried does the following:

1. Topologically-sort the graph into a list
2. Profile the nodes to get an idea of how long they take to execute.
3. Generate an execution plan. Using N worker threads, "fill in" their schedules task-by-task, in reverse (so, starting with the terminal node). Where dependencies cause waits, this is a gap in the schedule.
4. Now when the graph is run, we just follow the plan and only have to wait when a node's dependencies are planned for different threads.

Another technique I tried is to just allow workers to request the next available node from the topologically sorted list. This is fast-ish, but doesn't come close to generating a plan in advance.

The reason I think my solution is not optimal is because there are many ways to topologically sort a graph, which would yield different execution plans. So even if my approach is optimal, my implementation probably is not because I don't have any optimizing strategy to generating the list for the moment.

I think an execution plan with the fewest waits would be optimal, but I feel like I'm making this up as I go along.

Comment: Check out topological sort

Comment: @MitchelPaulin there's no problem with topological sort here; the question is about finding the optimal way to parallelize it.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any problem with your way of doing things. Why do you think it might not be optimal?

Comment: @n.m. I added more explanation as to what I've tried already.

Comment: You would need prior estimates of run-time of each task. Then you probably could do dynamic programming to find approximately optimal order, but I suppose finding perfectly optimal one might be NP-hard.

Comment: Are you looking for minimum latency or maximum throughput?

Comment: If you can create any number of threads (more than available physical processors), any simple technique will do. You don't actually need any topological sort, you can work directly from your task graph. Or you can go with any topological sort, the result will always be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution of Directed Acyclic Graph of tasks in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354899/execution-of-directed-acyclic-graph-of-tasks-in-parallel)